# D3 Path in Group does not show up in Firefox, only shows up in Chrome

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have the following - I've been tinkering around with it for a while, but I can't seem to get the path to appear in Firefox. Does anyone have any clue why? The circles show up. Firefox code inspector also gives it a size of 0x0.

```
<g transform="translate(85 460)" class="avatar">
  <circle cy="0" cx="0" r="6" class="base"></circle>
  <path transform="translate(0, 0) rotate(0) scale(1)" fill="black" d="M 0,0, L 0,8, L 10,0 Z"></path>
  <circle cy="0" cx="0" r="3" class="dot"></circle>
</g>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

EDIT:
Full svg:

```
<svg style="border: 1px solid black;" height="500" width="500">
  <image height="500" width="500" y="0" x="0" xlink:href="image.jpg"></image>
  <path style="opacity: 1;" d="M85,460Q81,150,85,110C91,49.99999999999999,113,60,125,60S162.75,77,165,110S131,250,140,280S204,305.5,225,310S268.75,322,280,310S291,254,300,230S328,150,340,150S371,209,380,230S394.75,278,400,290S410.5,307,415,310S424,310,430,310S449.75,307,455,310S463.5,324,465,330S465,338.75,465,350Q465,357.5,465,405" class="path selected"></path>
  <path d="M110,395L380,395" class="path"></path>
  <g transform="translate(85 460)" class="avatar">
    <circle cy="0" cx="0" r="6" class="base"></circle>
    <path transform="rotate(0) scale(1)" fill="black" d="M 0,0, L 0,8, L 10,0 Z"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Your snippet is useless without the `<svg>` parent element.  Please post a full example.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau - provided!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataBNF) if a comma occurs in a path it must have a number on either side of it.

Your path is invalid and Firefox rendering of the path is correct. I don't know if there is a Chrome bug on its invalid rendering of this path bug if there isn't you could create one.

To get your path to work in FF, remove the stray commas:

```
<path transform="rotate(0) scale(1)" fill="black" d="M 0,0 L 0,8 L 10,0 Z"></path>
```